# STM32 & lwIP - SHTML page not rendering - source code displayed instead

Tags: stm32, lwip, shtml

I'm trying to get an SSI page running on my STM32 using lwIP. When I open a .html page all is displayed fine. But .shtml pages will not be rendered and only the source code becomes visible.

This [post](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=508122) leads me to look for the mimetype using wget:

```sh
$ wget http://192.168.15.12/index.html
--2021-12-23 22:32:10--  http://192.168.15.12/index.html
Connecting to 192.168.15.12:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html.1            [ <=>                ]   1,92K  --.-KB/s    in 0,001s  

2021-12-23 22:32:10 (3,29 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [1971]

$ wget http://192.168.15.12/monitor.shtml
--2021-12-23 22:32:21--  http://192.168.15.12/monitor.shtml
Connecting to 192.168.15.12:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘monitor.shtml’

monitor.shtml.1         [ <=>                ]   1,92K  --.-KB/s    in 0,001s  

2021-12-23 22:32:21 (2,03 MB/s) - ‘monitor.shtml’ saved [1965]
```

It seems, that the mimetype is set wrong for shtml (`text/plain` instead `text/html shtml`?).

Does anyone know how to correct this?

---

Adding meta to HTML head does not help:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html shtml; charset=utf-8">
```

The meta content type seems to be ignored...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - I found it. The mimetype was set by the Perl script makefsdata. There was no rule for shtml file endings. So I added the rule to the header:

```perl
    open(HEADER, "> /tmp/header") || die $!;
    if($file =~ /404/) {
    print(HEADER "HTTP/1.0 404 File not found\r\n");
    } else {
    print(HEADER "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n");
    }
    print(HEADER "Server: lwIP/pre-0.6 (http://www.sics.se/~adam/lwip/)\r\n");
    if($file =~ /\.html$/) {
    print(HEADER "Content-type: text/html\r\n");
    } elsif($file =~ /\.shtml$/) {
    print(HEADER "Content-type: text/html shtml\r\n");
    } elsif($file =~ /\.gif$/) {
    print(HEADER "Content-type: image/gif\r\n");
    } elsif($file =~ /\.png$/) {
    print(HEADER "Content-type: image/png\r\n");
    } elsif($file =~ /\.jpg$/) {
    print(HEADER "Content-type: image/jpeg\r\n");
    } elsif($file =~ /\.class$/) {
    print(HEADER "Content-type: application/octet-stream\r\n");
    } elsif($file =~ /\.ram$/) {
    print(HEADER "Content-type: audio/x-pn-realaudio\r\n");    
    } else {
    print(HEADER "Content-type: text/plain\r\n");
    }
    print(HEADER "\r\n");
    close(HEADER);
```

Now it works!

---

> https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/lwip-devel/2021-12/msg00029.html

Comment: For Raspberry Pico W users: I use makefsdata in my projects and I see it is missing the shtml mimetype. I added shtml support to it like you show above and it works now!  File: /home/pi/pico/pico-sdk/lib/lwip/src/apps/http/makefsdata/makefsdata